# How to filter XML elements using LINQ query for one attribute/field containing a particular substring?

Tags: asp.net, attributes, linq-to-xml, filtering, substring

Example:

```
<Item name="item1">
    <mode = "ax, bx" />
</Item>
<Item name="item2">
    <mode = "bx, cx" />
</Item>
<Item name="item3">
    <mode = "cx, dx" />
</Item>
```

In the example above I would like to extract all the items with modes containing "cx".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Seems to me all of you are right, so I'll just select the first one that answered and +1 to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML in the example is not well formed. Assuming you meant:

```
<Items>
  <Item name="item1">
    <mode>ax, bx</mode>
  </Item>
  <Item name="item2">
    <mode>bx, cx</mode>
  </Item>
  <Item name="item3">
    <mode>cx, dx</mode> 
  </Item>
</Items>
```

you can do:

```
var els=from el in XDocument.Parse(inxml).Descendants("Item")
where el.Element("mode").Value.Contains("bx")
select el;
```

Comment: what is `inxml` here  in your answer it is giving me error while writing the query `Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'? D:\RND\TinyMce\Default.aspx.cs 148 30 D:\RND\TinyMce\
`

Comment: it's a string containing your xml

Comment: also, looking at the error you get, seems you should add `using System.Linq; using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: I have already added the reference of the above two namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

That is not legal XML (mode is an element name, you can set it equal to a string), but you should be able to do something like this, assuming that the string you are matching is the element value:

```
doc.Descendants("Item").Where( item => item.Elements("mode").Any( mode => mode.Value.Contains("cx")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a well formed XML doc:

```
<Items>
  <Item name="item1">
    <mode>ax, bx</mode>
  </Item>
  <Item name="item2">
    <mode>bx, cx</mode>
  </Item>
  <Item name="item3">
    <mode>cx, dx</mode> 
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Do something like this:

```
XElement items = XElement.Load(@"C:\items.xml");

var filteredItems = from item in items.Descendants("Item")
            where item.Element("mode").Value.Contains("cx")
            select item;

foreach (var item in filteredItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FirstAttribute.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
item2
item3
```